# How can I calculate yearly sales difference by Year (not in a subsequent row) in R?

Tags: r

```
Year=c(2011,2011,
       2012,2012,
       2013,2013)
Category=c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
Sales=c(87635,64576,72368,25764,25863,45786)
df=data.frame(Year,Category,Sales)
```

How can I calculate yearly sales difference by Year not by Category (not in a subsequent row)?

Expected output:
[image]

I use mutate function to calculate but does not work.

```
df%>% mutate(volumediff= Sales - lag(Sales, default = Sales[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify it is the difference between group A and group B, however, here is the solution to your question:

```
Year = c(2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013)
Category = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
Sales = c(87635, 64576, 72368, 25764, 25863, 45786)
df = data.frame(Year, Category, Sales)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(
    Difference = Sales[Category == "A"] - Sales[Category == "B"]
  )
```